# Post a picture to Twitter with iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, image

I am completely new to using Twitter APIs on ios4.
I'm looking for the easiest way to post a uiimage to the user's page.
How to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use http://dev.twitpic.com/

post your image in http request here.. post comment if you need help

Here is the code -

```
-(void)postToTwitter
{

    // create the URL
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitpic.com/1/uploadAndPost.xml"];

    // create the connection
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // change type to POST (default is GET)
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    // create data
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *username = emailTextField.text;
    NSString *password = passTextField.text;

    NSString *consumer_token=@"consumer token";
    NSString *consumer_secret=@"consumer secret ";
    NSString *oauth_token=@"oauth token";
    NSString *oauth_secret=@"oauth secret";
    NSString *api_key=@"api key";

    NSString *message = commentTxt.text;


    // just some random text that will never occur in the body
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    // header value
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
    // set header
    [postRequest addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // username part
     [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[username dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     // password part
     [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // api_key
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[api_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // consumer_token
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[consumer_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // consumer_secret
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"consumer_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[consumer_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //oauth_token
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[oauth_token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //oauth_secret
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_secret\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[oauth_secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // message part
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // media part
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media\"; filename=\"fish.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    img=[cFun correctImageOrientation:img];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 90);

    // add it to body
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // final boundary
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // add body to post
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

    // pointers to some necessary objects
    //NSURLResponse* response;
    //NSError* error;
    [activity_bg setHidden:NO];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah works perfect;here the oauth_token is engine.key and oauth_secret = engine.secret where engine is SA_OAuthTwitterEngine class