# Can we post image on twitter using twitter API in Android?

Tags: android, twitter

I had successfully integrate twitter API and I am able to post text from my device but I want to know two things

1. Is is possible to post Image on twitter using API in Android ?
2. In twitter we used `OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` tokens.I passing token values on second argument in below code is it ok ? or I have to leave it blank ?

   ```
   String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, OAuth_token_key);
   String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, OAuth_token_secret);
   ```

I searched to know whether is it possible to `post image on twitter using twitter API in Android` but I have not found any link that I know whether it is possible or not.

**I got one similar post image issue for iPhone** and [there is a answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497582/post-a-picture-to-twitter-with-iphone). I don't know about iPhone so I can't know weather it is right answer or not.Here is a link of similar question of post image for iPhone

Please help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes You can post the Image on the Twitter.

AIK, there are two methods to upload the photo to the Twitter.

With **First** you have to implemente the Twitter API and use [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609656/can-we-post-image-on-twitter-using-twitter-api-in-android) to upload the Photot to the Twitter.

Sorry for the Example. as i dont get any example for how to use this.

With **Second** you can do this with the help of the twitPic4j API. 
Just add the API for twitPic4j and write below code to upload the photo.

Code:

```
File picture = new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/"+filename+".jpg");  
// Create TwitPic object and allocate TwitPicResponse object 
TwitPic tpRequest = new TwitPic(TWITTER_NAME, TWITTER_PASSWORD); 
TwitPicResponse tpResponse = null;  
// Make request and handle exceptions                            
try {         
        tpResponse = tpRequest.uploadAndPost(picture, customMessageEditText.getText()+" http://www.twsbi.com/");

} 
catch (IOException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace(); 
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} 
catch (TwitPicException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid Username and Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
// If we got a response back, print out response variables                               
if(tpResponse != null) {         
       tpResponse.dumpVars();
       System.out.println(tpResponse.getStatus());
       if(tpResponse.getStatus().equals("ok")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Photo posted on Twitter.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //picture.delete();
       }
 }
```

Above code works in for my case.

Hope you got the sollution with the second one and i dont know how to use the first one.

Enjoy. :)

**Updated**

If still it not works for you and try some project listed below:

[Example 1](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample)

[Example 2](https://github.com/fbrunel/twitterdroid)

[Example 3](https://github.com/fmaker/Tweety)

[Example 4](https://github.com/cacois/TweetView)

Hope that will help you.

Happy Coding.

**==================================**

**FOR erdomester and Updated answer**

**==================================**

Please check my first link given with Example1 and its api: [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)
So, if any library that stop giving functionality to upload image on twitter, you can use other library for same. Please check and read regrading Twitter4j.

Check Twitter4J API to upload file to Twitter: [Twitter4j Image Upload](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/media/ImageUpload.html)

For instance help you can also check below code to upload image file on Twitter.

Code to upload Image:

```
    /**
 * To upload a picture with some piece of text.
 * 
 * 
 * @param file The file which we want to share with our tweet
 * @param message Message to display with picture
 * @param twitter Instance of authorized Twitter class
 * @throws Exception exception if any
 */

public void uploadPic(File file, String message,Twitter twitter) throws Exception  {
    try{
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
        status.setMedia(file);
        twitter.updateStatus(status);}
    catch(TwitterException e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you more for your query.

Thanks to **eredomester** to notify me that tweetpic is no more working for Twitter. But please dont do downvote to answer untill you have not fully search on the given reply. Given library Twitter4J in Example1 gives clear idea about uploading image to twitter and you can easily implement it.

For more help and code you can also check: [Twitter Upload media](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/media)

**Note:**  To use this please make sure you have latest jar file. I have used [twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.2.5/twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar) or more for this.

**Please comment me instead of downvoting this answer, if you facing any issue in this.**

Comment: this code is worked upto last week.now it saying invalid username and password.what is the problem i not getting it.i am entering correct passward and user name

Comment: @sai: check username and password of it. Or please remove that app and install it again and then check it.

Comment: Twitter API v 1.0 is now depricated, please update the link to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: Correct your link IMHO

Comment: @erdomester please write proper word. What do you mean by IMHO ?

Comment: @erdomester Its ok. But please be sure before commenting on others question and answers. because moderator are keep watching it and tracking it.

Comment: There is no TwitPic any more so does anyone know a solution? More info at http://blog.twitpic.com/2014/10/twitpics-future/

Comment: @erdomester please check my updated answer. And please stop doing downvote to my answers. It is flag by moderator.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer your updated answer of twitter4j helped me.. thanks.
erdomester you should try this friend..

Comment: this link is also helpful http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/writing-an-android-twitter-client-with-image-upload-using-twitter4j/

Comment: @DeepakPanwar yes, you link is also helpful. Its showing the use of the Twitter4J for uploading image on Twitter while i have only updated the main part of it.

Comment: ok, But thanks for helping other developers. Because in hard times you guys are boon to us.

Answer (score 2):

> Is is possible to post Image on twitter using API in Android ?

Yes you can upload Images to Twitter after successful Authentication Using [Twitter Media Uplload](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media).

> In twitter we used OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN and OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
>   tokens.I passing token values on second argument in below code is it
>   ok ? or I have to leave it blank ?

You should add both Token and Token Secret Key it will be useful for `setTokenWithSecret` methos of Tiwtter in which you have to send both Token and Token Secret..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can post image on twitter using Twitter api like twitter4j but I will suggest you to do using HttpPost class and DefaultHttpClient class because its good in practice and you dont need to add any external twitter api to it.

Comment: Do you have any link for that ? and if we used httppost then no need to add external twitter api ?

Comment: Look when we upload photo without using any external api on twitter we have to upload it in Multi-part/form. just go to this link and study about twitter rest api documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media and if my answer helped you plz upvote it.