# Which the Easy technique to tweet the Image on Twitter with the Message and Using Twitter Auth?

Tags: android, android-layout, twitter, android-emulator, twitter-oauth

I want to implement the Twitter in My Application.
With that, i want to Upload the Photo on it.
I also want to use the default Auth of the Twitter then Which one is the Best way to post photo on one button click and get message that the photo is posted on twitter.

I want any Simple Demo that help me for my application.

Thanks.

Comment: check out this  link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609656/can-we-post-image-on-twitter-using-twitter-api-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this following link

[this](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TwitterHelper.java#L860)

and please so this below method in that

```
 public String postPicture(String fileName) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String provider = preferences.getString("pictureService","yfrog");

    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        MediaProvider mProvider ;
        if (provider.equals("yfrog"))
            mProvider = MediaProvider.YFROG;
        else if (provider.equals("twitpic"))
            mProvider = MediaProvider.TWITPIC;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Picture provider " + provider + " unknown");

        String accessTokenToken = account.getAccessTokenKey();
        String accessTokenSecret = account.getAccessTokenSecret();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(PropertyConfiguration.MEDIA_PROVIDER,mProvider);
        props.put(PropertyConfiguration.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,accessTokenToken);
        props.put(PropertyConfiguration.OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,accessTokenSecret);
        props.put(PropertyConfiguration.OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY,TwitterConsumerToken.consumerKey);
        props.put(PropertyConfiguration.OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,TwitterConsumerToken.consumerSecret);
        Configuration conf = new PropertyConfiguration(props);

        ImageUploaderFactory factory = new ImageUploaderFactory(conf);
        ImageUpload upload = factory.getInstance(mProvider);
        String url = upload.upload(file);
        return url;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: Customise this generated block
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will check it later. And Accept your answer.

Comment: Is there any other Example or demo that is use to implement the twitter to tweet the photo on Twitter ?