# How can I upload an Image to Twitter From Android App

Tags: android, twitter, image-upload

I have performed Twitter Integration in Android. I have already done status(message posting part). But i am unable to post the picture on Twitter.
Kindly Let me know ASAP step by step.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609656/can-we-post-image-on-twitter-using-twitter-api-in-android